Worldchain Transaction execution reverted
I'm trying to create a code that sends Worldcoin through Worldchain using a master wallet that pays for the gas, but when I try to send it, I get an error. I’m not sure what’s causing it; this is the error:
(console.log for debug)
ETH balance in wei for paying fees: 453514483975334
Formatted ETH balance for paying fees: 0.000453514483975334
Current Worldcoin balance: 1.0 WLD
Data to transfer:
{
  "from": "0xD6C7481C875fBb69a07eC4e39Df6c690ABC69568",
  "to": "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F",
  "value": 1000000000000000000n,
  "gas": 500000,
  "deadline": 1731459014,
  "data": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000009ab93ebb695c119efd89a0e44919fb0d6aba2dc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000"
}
Transaction sent: 0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161

Error: transaction execution reverted (action="sendTransaction", data=null, reason=null, invocation=null, revert=null, transaction={ "data": "", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "to": "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F" }, receipt={ "_type": "TransactionReceipt", "blobGasPrice": null, "blobGasUsed": null, "blockHash": "0x05fe89a7c818f1d53c955eaeeb2879dc271457a3e6d1ca1373c82b6bb367c775", "blockNumber": 6059890, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": "112698", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "gasPrice": "1000264", "gasUsed": "25695", "hash": "0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161", "index": 2, "logs": [  ], "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "root": null, "status": 0, "to": "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.4)
    at makeError (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at assert (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:149:15)
    at checkReceipt (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider.js:1127:35)
    at JsonRpcProvider.txListener (/home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider.js:1173:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'sendTransaction',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    data: ''
  },
  receipt: TransactionReceipt {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    to: '0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    contractAddress: null,
    hash: '0xc32c9a7ddcfd29c84915ca77e8df885a70998d216725d5c48e435506e5d12161',
    index: 2,
    blockHash: '0x05fe89a7c818f1d53c955eaeeb2879dc271457a3e6d1ca1373c82b6bb367c775',
    blockNumber: 6059890,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    gasUsed: 25695n,
    blobGasUsed: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 112698n,
    gasPrice: 1000264n,
    blobGasPrice: null,
    type: 2,
    status: 0,
    root: undefined
  },
  shortMessage: 'transaction execution reverted'
}

Code that is generating the error:
const { ethers } = pkg;
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

const forwarderArtifact = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./artifacts/contracts/ERC2771Forwarder.sol/ERC2771Forwarder.json'), 'utf-8')
);

class WorldChain {
    async transfer(address, amount, privateKeyForGas, privateKeyForWLD) {
        try {
            const RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL;
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS_WORLDCHAIN = "0x2cFc85d8E48F8EAB294be644d9E25C3030863003";
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER = "0x56Ef28F9F0c856ce37AC10A60B9Fd1152A45875F";
            const ABI_TRANSFER = [
                "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
                "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
                "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)"
            ];
    
            const providerForGas = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const walletForGas = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForGas, providerForGas);

            const providerForWLD = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const walletForWLD = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForWLD, providerForWLD);

            const forwarder = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER, forwarderArtifact.abi, walletForGas);

            const wldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS_WORLDCHAIN, ABI_TRANSFER, walletForWLD);

            const balance = await wldContract.balanceOf(walletForWLD.address);
            const decimals = await wldContract.decimals();

            const ethBalanceForGas = await providerForGas.getBalance(walletForGas.address);
            console.log("Saldo de ETH en wei para pagar comisiones:", ethBalanceForGas.toString());
            const formattedEthBalanceForGas = ethers.formatUnits(ethBalanceForGas, "ether");
            console.log("Saldo de ETH formateado para pagar comisiones:", formattedEthBalanceForGas);

            const formattedBalance = ethers.formatUnits(balance, decimals).replace('.', ',');
            console.log(`Saldo actual de Worldcoin: ${formattedBalance} WLD`);

            const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amount, decimals);
            const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
            const forwardRequestData = {
                from: walletForWLD.address,
                to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER,
                value: ethers.parseEther(amount),
                gas: 500000,
                deadline: deadline,
                data: wldContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [address, amountInWei]),
            };

            console.log("Datos para transferir:", forwardRequestData);

            const domain = {
                name: 'ERC2771Forwarder',
                version: '1',
                chainId: 480,
                verifyingContract: CONTRACT_ADDRESS_FORWARDER
            };

            const types = {
                ForwardRequest: [
                    { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
                    { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
                    { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'deadline', type: 'uint256' },
                    { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
                ]
            };

            const signature = await walletForWLD.signTypedData(domain, types, forwardRequestData);

            forwardRequestData.signature = signature;

            console.log("Firma para transferir:", forwardRequestData.signature);

            const tx = await forwarder.execute(forwardRequestData, {
                /*value: amountInWei,*/
                gasLimit: (500000).toString(),
            });
            console.log(`Transacción enviada: ${tx.hash}`);

            await tx.wait();
            console.log(`Transacción recibida: ${tx.hash}`);

            return {
                status: 'success',
                transactionHash: tx.hash
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return {
                status: 'error',
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    }
}

export default new WorldChain();

I am using the OpenZeppelin ERC2771Forwarder contracts to make the main wallet pay for the gas and the user's private key pay for the WLD.
I tried deploying the contract on the Worldchain network; Worldscan indicates that it was deployed without issues. However, when I attempt to transfer, I get the previously mentioned error. The main wallet has ETH (which pays for the gas), and the user’s wallet (which transfers the WLD) also has tokens.
